# Horizontal Number Picker for android and ios

Tags: android, ios, scroll

So for the past week or so, I've been trying various methods to implement a horizontal number picker for a cross platform app I've been working on,

This is pretty much the look and feel I am going for,

[Scroller GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TCrM.gif)

and have tried the following links I've found by searching around

github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel

github.com/Akkyie/AKPickerView-Swift (It doesnt actually distort when I use it in swift)

(and also have tried using android's built-in horizontal scroll view and some resizing of the contents, but the look was clunky and not natural)

Any suggestions on how to best approach this problem? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HorizontalWheelView](https://github.com/shchurov/HorizontalWheelView) library. Its very easy to implement.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but will I actually be able to have text replace the marks on the wheel? Looking at the API, I don't think I can

Comment: Yes you can do that. Only thing is you have to calculate and manage the spacing part. In project, Library->Drawer class,  Goto drawNormalMark() method. Here, instead of canvas.drawLine, replace, canvas.drawText("Dummy",x,(top+bottom)/2,paint);